# Using database tables as objects?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I just started working on an existing (starting) project with the purpose of reorganizing it structurally and in performance as well. I usually work with EF as a framework but I am familiar with Linq-to-sql and ADO as well. What I am seeing is that right now the web application is using the actual database tables & views as objects inside the code, so, for example, you have table 'foo' they would go on and use it as an object instead of using classes to pass through data inside the app and finally inserting it into the DB/table. Since I never saw this and was not aware of it, I wonder, is this a "good" practice, I mean Microsoft did make it possible to do it like this so whats the "real" purpose, are there advantages/downsides?

Thank you all for your responses!
Kind regards

Comment: What does it mean to "use" a SQL table "as an object"? Are you saying they're using `DataTable` instead of a POCO class or EF? If so, no, that's not very good practice at all. The advantage is the guy who wrote the code initially got to spend more time watching anime instead of doing his job. The disadvantages are that you've got this opaque ball of goo that's annoying and error-prone to use, instead of a strongly typed class that's easy to use.

Comment: Sorry for the poor description, let me rephrase it with more detailed information. First of all they are using LinQ-To-Sql (dbml file), there is a table 'foos' lets say it has a string property "name". Normally i would go on and create a class 'foo' that has a prop name of type string and use it along the app and than call the DBContext.Foos and insert my object "foo" into it. But they are using Foos (the table) everywhere in the app, as return type for funcs, List<Foos> and so on so they are using the table directly as you would use a class object. Never saw this and i have my doubts about it

Comment: *"But they are using Foos (the table) everywhere in the app"* -- no, they are not. That's a SQL table. The application is in C#. Tell me what they are actually doing. What is `Foo` in their code? What is the actual thing? What is the type? What is the class? Who defined it? They aren't just magically importing the DB into .NET; this is code that came from somewhere.

Comment: In Visual Studio, right-click on `Foo` and select "Go To Definition" from the context menu.

Comment: I don't get how you have used Entity Framework and not seen that it creates the POCOs from the database for you if you follow a Database first method.  So if I have a database with tables 'Foo' and 'Bar' and they have columns of Id and Description both.  If I add an EF ADO.NET model and then just reference the database tables, it creates objects for me.  I don't consider it bad form to make a repo that utilizes these objects themselves and do it all the time.  It would only be bad form if you a drastically changing business logic to them and then attempting to manipulate something back.

Comment: Well that is because i never used database first method and did not used dbml files a lot in the past but your answer makes a lot of sense now. I did not even think about the fact i could just F12 on the 'foo' object and well yeah it took me to the DBML designer, shame on me :). Thank you for clearing that out for me and i agree on the fact that changes to the business logic could potentially create more work afterwards using it like this. Thank you all for your answers i really appreciate it ! Take care, kind regards.

Comment: @djangojazz , can't i mark your response as answer ?

Comment: I expanded on my comment on experiences I have had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since you liked my comment I will expand.  Let's say I have tables

```
Foo
FooId int 
Desc varchar(32)

Bar
BarId int
Desc varchar(32)
```

Now let's pretend I actually have many more and say 50 tables.  I would not want to create all that by hand as it would be kind of nuts.  Back in the day with ADO.NET you would create DataTables and potentially hand craft well formed objects.  Well with Linq To SQL they made a document to handle most of the modeling for you but it was pretty limited to near identical to what the database looked like.  But with Entity Framework MS took it a step farther.  Now you have a database layer, an intermediary layer, and an object layer.  Suffice to say you can even manipulate and create objects over and above what your 'context' wants.

But all that aside let's say I create an Entity Framework 6.1.3 model and select my database and select Database first.  I get a model representation as I add objects and they are stored under a context for me.  As far as EF is concerned these objects ARE the tables.  You just do something like

```
using(var context = new DBContext())
{
    var newFoo = new Foo { Id = 1, Desc = "A" };
    context.Foo.Add(newFood);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I just added and saved a new Foo object and I did not have to do ANY code creation of a POCO object.  EF did that for me when running the custom tool by selecting the model object and right clicking and selecting 'Run Custom Tool'.  Essentially this is just running the data to generate the POCO's and settings for you.  Or code writing code in the T4.  You can update the T4 to change settings but I don't recommend getting too crazy.

The method you are already going down is better.  Just Wrap the code in new methods and voila you have a repository.  The advantage of a repository over just doing say EF contexts inline is you can mix technologies or change them out as needed.  The only thing I would say would be to keep the objects you use as what the EF or other technology generates.  Or maybe you have some business logic with properties that auto invoke, well you don't want them to pollute your EF but they are fine in a repo pattern.  Repository patterns IMHO should just be a mediator for your CRUD operations to sit between a retrieval technology and a calling portion.

Comment: Thank you so much for you time and effort ! I am so used to using objects (classes i create) seperately from the DBcontext itself that i was kind of confused when i saw tables be used like objects outside of the CRUD actions to/from the database. I like seperation between Database related actions and codewise logic and i guess that this habbit made me NOT think further than my nouse is long :) Thank you ! Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

I have seen repositories used as objects in Java and C# before.  I suspect this is what you are talking about here.  If so, there is a significant tradeoff.  As with mot tools, how you use it is more important than if you use it and so understanding the tradeoffs is more important having a blanket use rule.

Usually with a repository, we have an object which is responsible for storing and getting our data.  This can act like a database table but is an abstraction, actually, that sits in between your database and your application.  Into this you persist objects, and from it you request objects.  The repository has no knowledge of the internals of the objects and only knows how to store them or get them.  It is a common pattern in Spring, for example.

A repository is very similar to data access objects (and in fact some people argue they are the same thing and others argue they are not).

The advantage is you have this abstraction so later if you want to store the objects somewhere else (say, you want to write them to Kafka instead and later write them to the database), you have a repository that can do this.  So the repository doesn't have to tell you how it gets or persists the data.  It just has to implement an API that you decide on to do so.

A major advantage here is that you separate your business logic from your persistence logic (meaning you can change either one without worrying about the other).  The disadvantage is that these are still tightly coupled so the abstraction doesn't buy you as much as you might think and it costs more complexity than you might think it should.

I am sure there are code generators to do this against tables in SQL Server.  However, the instant you do this you are more or less tying yourself to API decisions of the code generators which partially defeats the purpose of having the abstraction there in the first place.

Comment: What you explain is actually exactly how i am using it :) Thank you for your time and answer though !